# Plans for eager loading for ActiveRecord in Subsonic 3?

Tags: activerecord, subsonic, subsonic3

Just curious if there are plans for eager loading using ActiveRecord in Subsonic 3.  Is there a roadmap out there?

It seems like a pretty sweet library.  Very similar to Rails but missing a few sweet spots.

Comment: I'd like to also add that I saw some comments requesting hooks into the query creation for logging and performance monitoring.  Is that planned too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of ways to do this right now - the first is to create partial of the generated class and create a new constructor with a boolean flag for eager loading - or what might be better is to create a static factory method (Product.SingleEager(1)) that goes and loads what you need.

The second way is to tweak the T4 template to do this for you.

I don't have any plans to offer a config switch for this since its one of the more hotly debated issues - I'd rather put the power in your hands :)